# Bash with AWS CLI - unable to locate credentials

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have a shell script which is supposed to download some files from S3 and mount an ebs drive. However, I always end up with "Unable to locate credentials".

I have specified my credentials with the `aws configure` command and the commands work outside the shell script. Could somebody, please, tell me (preferably in detail) how to make it work?

This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

AWS_CONFIG_FILE="~/.aws/config"

echo $1

sudo mkfs -t ext4 $1
sudo mkdir /s3-backup-test
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /s3-backup-test
sudo mount $1 /s3-backup-test

sudo aws s3 sync s3://backup-test-s3 /s3-backup/test

du -h /s3-backup-test
ipt (short version):
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`sudo` will change the `$HOME` directory (and therefore `~`) to /root, and remove most bash variables like AWS_CONFIG_FILE from the environment.  Make sure you do everything with aws as root or as your user, dont mix.

Make sure you did `sudo aws configure` for example. And try

```
sudo bash -c 'AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/root/.aws/config aws s3 sync s3://backup-test-s3 /s3-backup/test'
```

You might prefer to remove all the sudo from inside the script, and just sudo the script itself.

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right... this was the root of the problem (running the script with sudo but specifying the credentials as a normal user). Thanks

Comment: Had this problem in a VS Code Remote Container: `aws configure` ran as root but a npm script executing `aws codeartifact login` couldn't access the `~/.aws/credentials` file. Specifying the `containerUser` helped.

Answer (score 45):

The `unable to locate credentials` error usually occurs when working with different aws profiles and the current terminal can't identify the credentials for the current profile.

**Notice that you don't need to fill all the credentials via `aws configure` each time - you just need to reference to the relevant profile that was configured once.**

From the [Named profiles section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html) in AWS docs:

> The AWS CLI supports using any of multiple named profiles that are
> stored in the config and credentials files. You can configure
> additional profiles by using aws configure with the `--profile` option,
> or by adding entries to the config and credentials files.
>
> The following example shows a credentials file with two profiles. The
> first [default] is used when you run a CLI command with no profile.
> The second is used when you run a CLI command with the 
>  `--profile user1`
> parameter.

`~/.aws/credentials` (Linux & Mac) or `%USERPROFILE%\.aws\credentials` (Windows):

> ```
> [default]
> aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
> aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
>
> [user1]
> aws_access_key_id=AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE
> aws_secret_access_key=je7MtGbClwBF/2Zp9Utk/h3yCo8nvbEXAMPLEKEY
> ```

So, after setting up the specific named profile (**user1** in the example above) via `aws configure` or directly in the `~/.aws/credentials` file you can select the specific profile:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --profile user1
```

Or export it to terminal:

```
$ export AWS_PROFILE=user1
```

Comment: I completely agree with the export way. The reason behind it because in some scripts you can't pass the AWS profile every time. So, it's better to use export AWS_PROFILE.

Comment: What if you can't configure it because it's not a tty device? How can you use credentials that are in ENV vars for example?

Answer (score 24):

While you might have your credentials and config file properly located in ~/.aws, it might not be getting picked up by your user account.

Run this command to see if your credentials have been set:`aws configure list`

To set the credentials, run this command: `aws configure` and then enter the credentials that are specified in your ~/.aws/credentials file.

Answer (score 18):

Answering in case someone stumbles across this based on the question's title.

I had the same problem where by the AWS CLI was reporting `unable to locate credentials`.

I had removed the `[default]` set of credentials from my `credentials` file as I wasn't using them and didn't think they were needed. It seems that they are.

I then reformed my file as follows and it worked...

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=****
aws_secret_access_key=****
region=eu-west-2

[deployment-profile]
aws_access_key_id=****
aws_secret_access_key=****
region=eu-west-2
```

Comment: My issue was similar. I had created a rake task in Rails that utilized some bash commands and I had removed the `[default]` block from my `.aws/credentials` file. I had been previously invoking a specific profile and it was working - so I just moved the credentials from that profile under `[default]` (which I added back).

Comment: The key here is the `default` profile was missing. I too deleted my default profile so I wouldn't accidently run a command w/o a named profile. ‍♀️

Answer (score 7):

This isn't necessarily related to the original question, but I came across this when googling a related issue, so I'm going to write it up in case it may help anyone else. I set up `aws` on a specific user, and tested using `sudo -H -u thatuser aws ...`, but it didn't work with awscli 1.2.9 installed on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
  % sudo -H -u thatuser aws configure list
        Name                    Value             Type    Location
        ----                    -----             ----    --------
     profile                <not set>             None    None
  access_key                <not set>             None    None
  secret_key                <not set>             None    None
      region                us-east-1      config_file    ~/.aws/config
```

I had to upgrade it using `pip install awscli`, which brought in newer versions of awscli (1.11.93), boto, and a myriad of other stuff (awscli docutils botocore rsa s3transfer jmespath python-dateutil pyasn1 futures), but it resulted in things starting to work properly:

```
  % sudo -H -u thatuser aws configure list
        Name                    Value             Type    Location
        ----                    -----             ----    --------
     profile                <not set>             None    None
  access_key     ****************WXYZ shared-credentials-file
  secret_key     ****************wxyz shared-credentials-file
      region                us-east-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

Answer (score 3):

A foolish and cautionary tail of a rusty script slinger:

I had defined the variable HOME in my script as a place were the script should go to build the platform.

This variable overwrote the `env` var that defines the shell users `$HOME`. So the AWS command could not find `~/.aws/credentials` because `~` was referencing the wrong place.

I hate to admit it, but I hope it helps saves someone some time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a `.aws/config` file with roles ensure sure your config file is correctly formatted. In my case I had forgotten to put the `role_arn =` in front of the arn.  The default profile sits in the `.aws/credentials` file and contains the access key id and secret access key of the iam identity.

The config file contains the role details:

```
[profile myrole]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/My-Role
source_profile = default
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::987654321098:mfa/my-iam-identity
region=ap-southeast-2
```

You can quickly test access by calling

```
aws sts get-caller-identity --profile myrole
```

If you have MFA enabled like I have you will need to enter it when prompted.

```
Enter MFA code for arn:aws:iam::987654321098:mfa/my-iam-identity:
{
    "UserId": "ARABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST:botocore-session-15441234567",
    "Account": "123456789012",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/My-Role/botocore-session-15441234567"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Was hitting this error today when running aws cli on **EC2**. My situations is I could get credentials info when running `aws configure list`. However I am running in a corporate environment that doing things like `aws kms decrypt` requires `PROXY`. As soon as I set proxy, the aws credentials info will be gone.

```
export HTTP_PROXY=aws-proxy-qa.cloud.myCompany.com:8099
export HTTPS_PROXY=aws-proxy-qa.cloud.myCompany.com:8099
```

Turns out I also have to set `NO_PROXY` and have the ec2 metadata address in the list `169.254.169.254`.  Also, since you should be going via an s3 endpoint, you should normally have `.amazonaws.com` in the no_proxy too.

```
export NO_PROXY=169.254.169.254,.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this trying to run an aws-cli command from roots cron.

Since credentials are stored in $HOME/.aws/credentials and I initialized aws-cli through *sudo*, $HOME is still /home/user/. When running from cron, $HOME is /root/ and thus cron cannot find the file.

The fix was to change $HOME for the specific cron job. Example:

```
00 12 * * * HOME=/home/user aws s3 sync s3://...
```

(alternatives includes moving, copying or symlinking the .aws dir, from /home/user/ to /root/)

Answer (score 0):

try adding sudo with aws command like `sudo aws ec2 command` and yes as [meuh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5008284/meuh) mentioned the awscli needs to be configured using sudo

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error if you've configured a profile other than default e.g. `aws configure --profile foobar`. If this is the case you need to specify the profile e.g. `aws s3 ls s3://xxx --profile foobar` Where 'foobar' is the name of the non-default profile configured.

Answer (score -3):

```
pip install --upgrade awscli
```

or

```
pip3 install --upgrade awscli
```

---